# Can I get a sport pilot license while taking Mirapex?

Tags: medical

May I get a sport pilot license while taking the medication Mirapex for Restless Leg Syndrome?

Comment: What research have you done beforehand?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! For questions about rules and regulations, please always tell us which country (or set of regulations) you're asking about. Are you asking about FAA rules?

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming you have never applied for a medical certificate:*

You need to ask your doctor. Sport pilots don't need to have a medical certificate, but they do need to be capable of operating an airplane safely. Mirapex is on the [do not issue, do not fly list](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/pharm/dni_dnf/), so the presumption is that you **cannot** fly while taking it. In order to legally fly solo or with passengers while taking Mirapex, your doctor *must* tell you that it's safe to do so.

Your doctor may tell you that it's not safe to fly while taking Mirapex. In that case, you only have two options: stop taking the medication (with the approval and supervision of your doctor), or don't fly (except as a student receiving instruction).

*If you **have** applied for a medical certificate ever in your life:* You need to get a medical certificate in order to fly solo or with passengers. In this case, you need to talk to an aviation medical examiner for advice; there's no way around this.

Comment: Your last paragraph is slightly incorrect: a private pilot (for example) can exercise sport privileges without a current medical. However, if their previous medical was denied or revoked then they can't fly under sport rules. AOPA has [some useful information](https://www.aopa.org/advocacy/advocacy-briefs/frequently-asked-questions-about-sport-pilot#pilots).

Comment: @Pondlife Thanks for the feedback. Looks like I was assuming that the asker has never been issued a medical certificate, and I forgot about the case where the asker has been issued a certificate but the certificate has lapsed. I should edit this answer to add more information about that.